# Simulating a process n times in R

Tags: r, simulation, stochastic-process

I've written an R script (sourced from [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/50030/simulation-of-geometric-brownian-motion-in-r)) simulating the path of a geometric Brownian motion of a stock price, and I need the simulation to run 1000 times such that I generate 1000 paths of the process  Ut = Ste^-mu*t, by discretizing the law of motion derived from Ut which is the bottom line of the solution to the question posted [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/64137/deriving-law-of-motion-by-itos-lemma/64147#64147).

The process also has n = 252 steps and discretization step = 1/252, also risk of sigma = 0.4 and instantaneous drift mu, which I've treated as zero, although I'm not sure about this. I'm struggling to simulate 1000 paths of the process but am able to generate one single path, I'm unsure which variables I need to change or whether there's an issue in my for loop that's restricting me from generating all 1000 paths. Could it also be that the script is simulating each individual point for 252 realization instead of simulating the full process? If so, would this restrict me from generating all 1000 paths? Is it also possible that the array I'm generating defined as U hasn't being correctly generated by me? U[0] must equal 1 and so too must the first realization U(1) = 1. The code is below, I'm pretty stuck trying to figure this out so any help is appreciated.

```
#Simulating  Geometric Brownian motion (GMB)
tau <- 1 #time to expiry
N <- 253 #number of sub intervals
dt <- tau/N #length of each time sub interval
time <- seq(from=0, to=N, by=dt) #time moments in which we simulate the process
length(time) #it should be N+1

mu <- 0 #GBM parameter 1
sigma <- 0.4 #GBM parameter 2
s0 <- 1 #GBM parameter 3

#simulate Geometric Brownian motion path
dwt <- rnorm(N, mean = 0, sd = 1) #standard normal sample of N elements
dW <- dwt*sqrt(dt) #Brownian motion increments
W <- c(0, cumsum(dW)) #Brownian motion at each time instant N+1 elements


#Define U Array and set initial values of U
U <- array(0, c(N,1)) #array of U
U[0] = 1
U[1] <- s0 #first element of U is s0. with the for loop we find the other N elements

for(i in 2:length(U)){
  U[i] <- (U[1]*exp(mu - 0.5*sigma^2*i*dt + sigma*W[i-1]))*exp(-mu*i)
}

#Plot 
plot(ts(U), main = expression(paste("Simulation of Ut")))
```

Answer (score 0):

This questions is quite difficult to answer since there are a lot of unclear things, at least to me.

To begin with, `length(time)` is equal to 64010, not `N + 1`, which will be 254.

If I understand correctly, the brownian motion function returns the position in one dimension given a time. Hence, to calculate this position for each time the following can be enough:

```
s0*exp((mu - 0.5*sigma^2)*time + sigma*rnorm(length(time),0,time))
```

However, this calculates 64010 points, not 253. If you replicate it 1000 times, it gives 64010000 points, which is quite a lot.

```
> B <- 1000
> res <- replicate(B, {
+   s0*exp((mu - 0.5*sigma^2)*time + sigma*rnorm(length(time),0,time))
+ })
> length(res)
[1] 64010000
> dim(res)
[1] 64010  1000
```

I know I'm missing the second part, the one explained [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/64137/deriving-law-of-motion-by-itos-lemma/64147#64147), but I actually don't fully understand what you need there. If you can draw the formula maybe I can help you.

In general, avoid programming in R using `for` loops to iterate vectors. R is a vectorized language, and there is no need for that. If you want to run the same code `B` times, the `replicate(B,{ your code })` function is your firend.